# How to convert dataframe object into Int64?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes. because they are not the same type of data, I try to convert it into one. But I get the following error, can someone help me with this?

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1JkV.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In the future, please include the error traceback as text in your question, not as a picture. Also, please include sample of your input dataframe. In this case, the `keyerror` indicates that `borocd` is not a valid column name in your dataframe

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure (like combining two custom objects) you are thinking is the correct way, but you could use the `object.__int__()`, `object.__float__()` (like `object.__init__()`) methods to get those.